# Unable to read white on black Data Matrix barcode

Tags: ios, ios8, barcode, datamatrix

Data Matrix barcode support was added to iOS 8 and I'm able to use it to read Data Matrix barcodes if they are black on white (dark on light). However, it never reads a white on black (light on dark) barcode.

Reads this fine:

[image]

Unable to read this:

[image]

Per Data Matrix ECC 200, light on dark should be supported.

Anyone have an idea how to get iOS 8 to read a light on dark Data Matrix barcode?

Comment: May I know which API you use?

Comment: @gabbler I'm using the native iOS barcode capability (`AVCaptureMetadataOutput`) and associated delegate (`AVCaptureMetadatOutputObjectsDelegate`).

Comment: Did you use your camera to scan the picture, or just pass in the picture for decoding?

Comment: I'm using the camera - iOS does not (currently) support passing in a picture for decoding.

Comment: I see the same result, don't know the reason though.

Comment: Do you expect decoded result of the second image to be the same as the first image? If so, you can invert the image colour of the second image, the resulting image looks like the first image.

Comment: There are other commercial barcode APIs that can help you decoding inverted barcodes (if this is an option at all).

Comment: @ssasa I am really hoping to use the native iOS capability. Seems silly to have to resort to another library when (almost) everything I need is part if iOS.

Comment: @bobnoble Did you find anything i mean solution? please share!

Comment: @BuntyMadan Unfortunately, no, have never found a solution to this. Currently looking at a couple of commercial libraries - Scandit and Manatee. In our testing for barcode types Code 29, Code 128, QR code and DataMatrix, Scandit performs slightly better than Manatee.

Comment: @bobnoble ok, thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: @bobnoble tried with https://manateeworks.com iOS SDK and working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the colors of your `AVCaptureSession` in real time, allowing you to read the Data Matrix code.

You can use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to invert the colors. It's fast and plugs in easily. Just invert and let AVFoundation find it as normal.

Comment: `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is for presenting the video as it is captured. Applying an invert filter would only invert what the user sees, not to the input of the `AVCaptureSession`, so don't see how that would help. Are you thinking of something else?

Comment: #facepalm - Yes, I'm thinking of something else :) What system are you using to capture the QR image? Before I edit my answer, are you processing a static image or using a live preview to capture the QR code?

Comment: It's Data Matrix (not QR Code). I'm using the native iOS barcode scanning and using live video.

Comment: Fixed my answer - see above :)

Comment: I don't think the output from GPUImage can be an input to an `AVCaptureSession` which is required to use the iOS barcode scanning on it.

Comment: Did anyone get this to work? I'm looking for a solution as well. ZXing on iOS doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Uniphonic The answer is to get the frames from the capture session, use CIFilter's to invert the image and use the new Vision framework on iOS11+ to detect barcodes from the inverted image.