# Matrix Barcode Reader | iOS SDK | AVFoundation | AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode

Tags: ios, matrix, avfoundation, barcode

```
Problem Statement
```

Unable to read `Matrix` Barcode using `AVFoundation` Framework, `Matrix` with White background works fine but the with Black background does't response.

```
Implementation
```

Using `AVFoundation` framework creating `AVCaptureSession` adding outputs and getting callback using `didOutputMetadataObjects` so incase of background even no response getting from the framework.

```
Does't Work
```

[image: Does't Work]

```
Works Fine
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AVFoundation does not support reading inverse color DataMatrix barcodes, though I've not found mention of that specifically in the documentation. Other developers have reported this as well: [Unable to read white on black Data Matrix barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580953/unable-to-read-white-on-black-data-matrix-barcode)

For now, the only solution I've found is to use a 3rd party commercial scanning library, such as Scandit or Manatee Works.